# Как определить порог (score) в google recaptcha v3?

Tags: php, symfony, recaptcha

Может у кого был опыт в этом.
Зарегестрировал recaptcha v3, прописал домен, получил токен и т.д с этим все ок.
В ответе приходит всё как пологается. Суть - нужно определить порог это в ответе $responseArray['score'] = может быть от 0.0 до 0.9 как описано в документации, что это с большей вероятностью пишет человек. У меня проверяется этот порог все ок. Я бы хотел узнать в самой панели google recaptcha есть ли возможность установить этот порог?
Если нет, то как мне в случае если больше 0.9 к примеру 1.0 или 3.0 отправить в google для статистики, что была попытка залогинться роботом или спам и т.д.
Вопрос скорее для тех, кто хорошо знает этот инструмент.

Фрагмент кода

```
class LoginController extends AbstractController
```

{
private const array SCORES = [
0.0,
0.2,
0.3,
0.4,
0.5,
0.6,
0.7,
0.8,
0.8,
0.9,
];

```
#[Route(path: '/login', name: 'app_login', methods: ['GET'])]
public function webLogin(): Response
{
    return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'LoginController'
    ]);
}

#[Route(path: '/check', name: 'login_check', methods: ['POST'])]
public function check(Request $request): Response
{
    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    $token = $request->request->get('token');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('secret' => 'xxxx', 'response' => $token)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);


    if (in_array($responseArray['score'], self::SCORES)) {
        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'response' => $responseArray
            ]
        );
    }else{
        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'response' => 'You are robot!'
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

}

Comment: вам рекапча присылает скор, зачем гуглу нужен этот скор обратно? Или вы хотите эту стату собирать где-то для себя?

Comment: Aleksey Vaganov Нет, не обратно. Я имею ввиду, то что можно ли самому в гугл админке установить сам этот порог к примеру я хочу иметь такой порог: (score)
0.0, 0,2, 0,3, 0,5 и все. А так по умолчанию гугл присылает ответ 0.9 и типа что если выше этого порога это уже зона риска.

Comment: так нельзя сделать

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov, да я так и понял. Спасибо.